# ValueError due to a missing element in color map

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx

I need to build a network where nodes (from `df1`) have some specific colors based on labels from a different dataset (`df2`). In `df1` not all the nodes have labelled assigned in `df2` (for example, because they have not been labelled yet, so they have currently nan value).
The below code should provide a good example on what I mean:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as mcolor

# Sample DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Node': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'Z'],
    'Edge': ['B', 'D', 'N', 'A', 'X', 'C']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'N', 'S', 'X'],
    'Attribute': [-1, 0, -1.5, 1, 1, 9, 0]
})

# Simplified construction of `colour_map`
uni_val = df2['Attribute'].unique()
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, len(uni_val)))
# Map colours to_hex then zip with
mapper = dict(zip(uni_val, map(mcolor.to_hex, colors)))
color_map =df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper).fillna('black')


G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Add Attribute to each node
nx.set_node_attributes(G, color_map, name="colour")

# Then draw with colours based on attribute values:
nx.draw(G,
        node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),
        with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

`Z` is not `df2` because `df2` was created considering only non NA values.
I would like to assign the color black to unlabelled nodes, i.e., for those nodes that are not in `df2`.
Trying to run the code above, I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: 'c' argument has 7 elements, which is inconsistent with 'x' and 'y' with size 8.
```

It is clear that this error is caused by the add of color black for missing, not included in color_map.
What it is not clear to me is how to fix the issue. I hope in some help for figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Z` is not in `df2`, but is one of the nodes, we should, instead of creating properties exclusively from `df2` we should [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) the `color_map` from [`nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.nodes.html) nodes with a `fill_value`:

```
# Create graph before color map:
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Create Colour map. Ensure all nodes have a value via reindex using nodes
color_map = (
    df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper)
        .reindex(G.nodes(), fill_value='black')
)
```

[image: defaulted graph]

---

`color_map` without reindex

```
df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper)

Nodes
A    #000080
B    #0080ff
C    #7dff7a
D    #ff9400
N    #ff9400
S    #800000
X    #0080ff
Name: Attribute, dtype: object
```

`nodes` (using nodes here since this will be all nodes in the Graph, rather than just those in `df2`)

```
G.nodes()

['A', 'B', 'D', 'N', 'X', 'Z', 'C']
```

[`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) to ensure all nodes are present in mapping:

```
df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper).reindex(G.nodes(), fill_value='black')

Nodes
A    #000080
B    #0080ff
D    #ff9400
N    #ff9400
X    #0080ff
Z      black  # <- Missing Nodes are added with specified value
C    #7dff7a
Name: Attribute, dtype: object
```

---

Complete Code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt, colors as mcolor

# Sample DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Node': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'Z'],
    'Edge': ['B', 'D', 'N', 'A', 'X', 'C']
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Nodes': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'N', 'S', 'X'],
    'Attribute': [-1, 0, -1.5, 1, 1, 9, 0]
})

# Simplified construction of `colour_map`
uni_val = df2['Attribute'].unique()
colors = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0, 1, len(uni_val)))
# Map colours to_hex then zip with
mapper = dict(zip(uni_val, map(mcolor.to_hex, colors)))

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df1, source='Node', target='Edge')
# Create Colour map. Ensure all nodes have a value via reindex
color_map = (
    df2.set_index('Nodes')['Attribute'].map(mapper)
        .reindex(G.nodes(), fill_value='black')
)
# Add Attribute to each node
nx.set_node_attributes(G, color_map, name="colour")

# Then draw with colours based on attribute values:
nx.draw(G,
        node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),
        with_labels=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Henry! As always, great and well-explained answer!

Comment: sorry, Henry, at the end of the run with the full dataset, I have got this error: `ValueError: 'c' argument must be a color, a sequence of colors, or a sequence of numbers, not dict_values`. Do you know why? `----> 6 nx.draw(G, node_color=nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values(),with_labels=True)`

Comment: You can try `node_color=list(nx.get_node_attributes(G, 'colour').values())` instead. I don't know which version of `matplotlib` started allowing any collection to scatter.

Comment: unfortunately it returns the same error. may I ask you which version of matplotlib you are using? Mine is 3.3.4

Comment: That version should work fine. This error can also occur if you have an invalid colour code as an attribute. Like changing to `fill_value='nonsense'` in the above code would produce that error. Double check your `color_map` and make sure that all appear to be valid hex or colour codes.

Comment: sorry to bother you, Henry, but I would like to ask you if you  know how to add the legend of the chosen colors via map? Happy to open a new question, if required. Thanks

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head. I'm more familiar with the computational side of networkx than the display side.

Comment: no problem at all. Thanks a lot Henry :)